# How can i convert "\xff\xfet\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00" into b'\xff\xfet\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00"' in python

Tags: python, byte

How can I convert "\xff\xfet\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00" into b'\xff\xfet\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00"' in python. All I need to do is somehow add the b' to it

Answer (score 0):

the `b'\xff\xfet\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00'` represent that its a byte type object. So if your string is `x="\xff\xfet\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00"`. Then to convert it into byte just use the builtin encode method.

```
x_byte=x.encode('utf-8')
print(x_byte)
```

Comment: how can i do it vice verse so b'\xff\xfet\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00' into "\xff\xfet\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00"